# Can I tell dplyr's select() to grab indexed rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to select the first 1000 rows of my data and also drop the final column storing the median. Is there a way to do this:

```
select(myTblDf, -median)
mySubset <- myTblDf[1:1000, ]
```

in a single dplyr `select()` invocation?

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably use `top_n` or `slice`

Comment: I think you need `slice` or `head` as `select` is for selecting columns i.e. if there are no grouping variable, `head` will be fine,  `select(myTblDdf, -median) %>% head(1000)` or else replace with `%>% slice(1:1000)`

Answer (score 4):

```
select(myTblDf, -median) %>% filter(row_number() <= 1000)
```

should also work, in addition to those suggested in comments.